# Pagination in firestore api

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to paginate documents with firestore beta. I am following the official [docs](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/list)

I see there is a pageSize param to say how many documents you want to show, but i dont see any offset option. Does anybody know how can i do a pagination system?

thank you

Comment: I was googling for how to specify number of results as a URL param when doing the query -- your question answered that for me -- upvote to the question, for being an answer.

Answer (score 16):

From your documentation link, I assume that you're using the REST API.  In the REST API, there is a `pageToken` parameter, which you can specify.  This can be derived from the `nextPageToken` returned from the previous request.

### Previous response

```
{
  "documents": [
    {
      object(Document)
    }
  ],
  "nextPageToken": ABCDEF1234567890,
}
```

### Next request

```
 projects/my-project/databases/my-database/documents or projects/my-project/databases/my-database/documents/chatrooms?pageSize=20&pageToken=ABCDEF1234567890
```

Answer (score 1):

Firestore range queries are based on an having anchor document. So you must know the (order-by properties of the) document that the range start with, and then use `ref.startAfter(anchorDdoc).limit(10)` (or `ref.startAfter(valueOfAnchorDoc).limit(10)`) to get the next page.

The Firestore server-side [Admin SDKs have an `offset()` call](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.11.x/Query#offset) that allows the server to determine the document to starts at. But the client-side SDKs do not have this method.

Comment: I have a question, if the we query with offset 20, does the quota requests count as 20? or it includes the previous 20, totaling 40? Thanks

Comment: Is there a way to get the total number of documents in a query if pagination is enabled? Because accessing the count property of the snapshot only returns the count of documents in that pagination block. Is there a way to know how many documents remain beyond what's already been shown in the paginated results?

Comment: Nope. The server would have to access each document for that, which defeats the purpose of pagination. If you want to cheaply and simply get the count of documents, it's best to keep a counter inside the database and update that as documents are added/removed. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation#solution_cloud_functions

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen so how to paginate data with firestore if we want to know all pages initially? Thanks

Comment: the offset method still charges you for the documents you offset as if you had downloaded the documents

Answer (score 0):

This may help paginating without page numbers (previous and next):

```
app.get('/page/next/:startAt',(req, res)=>{
      (async ()=>{
          try{
              const startAt = req.params.startAt;
              let query = db.collection('movies');
              let response = [];
              console.log(query);
              await query.orderBy('time', 'desc').where("time", "<", new Date(parseInt(startAt)*1000)).limit(16).get().then(snapshots => {
                let docs = snapshots.docs;

                for (let doc of docs){
                    console.log(doc.data());
                    const selectedItems = {
                        id: doc.id,
                        name: doc.data().name,
                        desp: doc.data().desp,
                        site: doc.data().site,
                        time: doc.data().time
                    }
                    response.push(selectedItems);
                }
                  return response;  //each then should return a vlue
              })
              return res.status(200).send(response);
          }catch (error){
              console.log(error);
              return res.status(500).send(error);
          }
      })();
    });


    app.get('/page/back/:backAt',(req, res)=>{
      (async ()=>{
          try{
              const backAt = req.params.backAt;
              let query = db.collection('movies');
              let response = [];
              console.log(query);
              await query.orderBy('time', 'desc').where("time", ">", new Date(parseInt(backAt)*1000)).limit(16).get().then(snapshots => {
                let docs = snapshots.docs;

                for (let doc of docs){
                    console.log(doc.data());
                    const selectedItems = {
                        id: doc.id,
                        name: doc.data().name,
                        desp: doc.data().desp,
                        site: doc.data().site,
                        time: doc.data().time
                    }
                    response.push(selectedItems);
                }
                  return response;  //each then should return a vlue
              })
              return res.status(200).send(response);
          }catch (error){
              console.log(error);
              return res.status(500).send(error);
          }
      })();
    });
```