# Does firestore support skip functionality?

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

> Summary: I want to use the 'skip' function used in MySql and MongoDb.
>   However, 'startAfter (number)' does not skip.

I am making a bulletin board now. Then I got a question.

This is a matter of page skip.

I use the basic method of moving pages directly to users.

However, I could not find any skip functions that Mysql or MongoDB used in the past.

This is part of my code.

```
return db.collection('boards').doc(title).collection('posts')
.orderBy('date').startAfter(2).limit(10).get()
```

So I want to skip two data from the data sorted by date.

However, any number in 'startAfter' will be taken from the first data.

Of course, I checked the following code in the official document.

```
return first.get().then(function (documentSnapshots) {
  // Get the last visible document
  var lastVisible = documentSnapshots.docs[documentSnapshots.docs.length-1];
  console.log("last", lastVisible);

  // Construct a new query starting at this document,
  // get the next 25 cities.
  var next = db.collection("cities")
          .orderBy("population")
          .startAfter(lastVisible)
          .limit(25);
});
```

However, the above method is very troublesome because it is possible to have existing data unconditionally.

Is not there a good way? I am waiting for a reply.

Comment: As Jason answered, there is no way to skip a number of documents in the client-side SDKs of Firestore. But the functionality *does* exist in the Admin SDKs, which are meant to be run in controlled environments. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48884777/pagination-in-firestore-api. But I highly recommend you get the hang of `startAfter` (and its siblings), since it is a much better fit for Firestore's data model.

Comment: @Frank: I normally refer to the Admin SDK for reference. I've used `offset` previously and forgotten about it. :S I've updated my answer.  Thanks.

Comment: It's a weird case of feature-mismatch between them. One of the reasons I like feature-parity, is that it reduces the memory requirements for memorizing our API. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Client SDKs

The documentation for this states:

> **fieldValuesOrDocumentSnapshot**
>
> *(repeatable any type or DocumentSnapshot)*
>
> The snapshot of the document the query results should start after or the field values to start this query after, in order of the query's order by.

Therefore, you are unable to simply specify the number of documents to skip.  You will either need to know a value from that second document (ID, field value, etc.) or get the first 2 documents, then use the snapshot of the second document, to generate your query.

## Admin SDK

With the Admin SDK, there is the [offset](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/0.13.x/Query#offset) method, which should allow you to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Sorry for my foolish question and i check Admin SDK, after i create on functions and update that use 'offset' really thank you Jason Berryman,

Comment: Might be useful for others, but offset charges you still for every document skipped!