# How to fetch all documents from a collection using Firestore API?

Tags: rest, api, google-cloud-firestore

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#making_rest_calls

Hi,

I want to fetch all the documents from my collection using REST for reporting purposes.

I tried using **list** method in API explorer but I am only getting max 30 documents at a time and for next page I have to use the **nextPageToken**.

I have even tried giving the **pageSize** to 100, even then it is returning only 30 documents as it is for maximum number of documents to return. Is there any way I can fetch all documents?

I have around 3-4k simple documents.

Answer (score 3):

The example here works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48889822/2441655

Example:
`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT/databases/(default)/documents/YOUR_DOC_PATH?pageSize=300`

You can use paging by finding the "nextPageToken" at the end of the json, then inserting it like so:
`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/YOUR_PROJECT/databases/(default)/documents/YOUR_DOC_PATH?pageSize=300&pageToken=NEXT_PAGE_TOKEN_HERE`

However it still limits the max pageSize to 300 for me. (odd that it limits it to 30 for you)