# PageInfo in Firestore not usable

Tags: firebase, go, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to use pagination in Firestore so I can save a query state and automatically allow users to submit a page token to start a query again. The challenge I am seeing with this is that Firestore does not offer a query token or page token to resume iteration. However, after looking through the docs for GoLang, it looks like there is an exported [`PageInfo()`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/firestore/v1.5.0/firestore/list_documents.go#L61-L62) method that returns a token I am interested in and an unexported [`fetch` method](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-go/blob/firestore/v1.5.0/firestore/list_documents.go#L76-L92).

Is there a method to use the exported PageInfo() values to allow me to fetch a new set of documents using that existing token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use pagination in Firestore Database you can use query cursors with `limit()` method as mentioned in [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#paginate_a_query). You can go through [this youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poqTHxtDXwU) to know more about it.

You may also consider using `pageSize` & `pageToken` query parameters and `nextPageToken` field with Firestore REST API as mentioned in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/list#query-parameters) to achieve pagination. There is a similar [StackoverFlow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48884777/pagination-in-firestore-api) which may help you.